# Can zeroisation of memory by xor-ing data with itself be optimized away in C?

Tags: c, memory, cryptography, xor

Sometimes, for security purposes, we need to zero out memory to prevent unintended access to sensitive data, say to securely delete a key after encrypting some data. The way most people suggest to do it is to write random data to an array containing the sensitive information because this cannot be optimized away by a compiler. It is well understood that naive use of functions like `memset` can be optimized away by an optimizing compiler due to the as-if rule if it is the last operation done to the data before it goes out of scope. Getting and writing random data is slow, though, and I may have found a solution. I want an expert opinion before deploying it in production code though.

Xor-ing anything with itself, by the very nature of the operator, always results in a value of zero, and it is very fast. Traversing a block of memory and xor-ing it with itself seems to be a very effective solution to the problem of zeroisation, but I'm worried it could be optimized away by a sufficiently good optimizing compiler. It is cross-platform and portable, and it doesn't require use of the standard library, except for the use of the `size_t` data type. I've included a reference implementation of what I mean below. In it I have a function called `nuke` which takes a pointer `data_to_zero` and iteratively xor's `size` bytes with itself.

```
void nuke (void *data_to_zero, size_t size)
{
    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        ((unsigned char*)data_to_zero)[i] ^= ((unsigned char*)data_to_zero)[i];
    }
}
```

This implementation is fairly slow, but is significantly faster than acquiring sufficiently random data and writing it to `data`. After optimization, it is faster than the `memset` implementations I have access to anyway, which is surprising.

I haven't learned assembly yet, but the assembly output after optimization with both GCC and Clang at the O2 and O3 level an 64-bit x86 processor have the `xorl` instruction in them somewhere in the code, sometimes twice. That indicates to me that xor-ing of the memory is actually happening, but I would like someone who knows what they're talking about to confirm.

Is this a viable solution?

Comment: You should use [`memset_s`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset#Notes) (C11).

Comment: Why do you think that writing zero by XORing is less likely to be optimised than writing zero any other way? The "as-if" explanation you provide applies identically, doesn't it`? Please elaborate on this in your question.

Comment: Looks like you can prevent optimization by accessing the object after cleaning. E.g., by setting the bytes to `i%256` and then calculating the XOR of all bytes.

Comment: Place memset() in nuke() and put nuke() in a separate translation unit. The compiler cannot see the optimization potential.

Comment: @DyZ: A compiler may perform any optimization that does not alter the “observable side effects” of the program as defined by the standard. Computing the checksum is only a way to fool the optimizer by obscuring what is happening. But there are multiple ways this can fail. If the checksum is never written anywhere (or used to compute something written), the compiler may see all operations contributing to it have no ultimate effect. And without a guarantee in some form, you cannot know that what fool’s today’s optimizer will fool tomorrow’s.

Comment: @ericpistpischil I understand this part. The computed xor can be used as a seed for the next wipe out and eventually returned from the main function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct way of doing this is to call the `memset_s()` function. It uses the volatile type qualifier to inform the compiler that the call to the memset_s() function should not be optimized out.

Unfortunately this solution may not be as efficient as possible, because of the nature of the volatile type, protecting from all kinds of optimizations, it may prevent the compiler from using the optimal assembly instructions and can result in less efficient code. Another problem with `memset_s()` is that it's introduced in C11.

If you can't use `memset_s()`, then you have to consider one of the following methods:

1. Another solution may be to "touch" the memory, by accessing the memory after the memset(), like so `*(volatile char*)pwd= *(volatile char*)pwd`.
   The problem with this solution is it may not work for all implementations.
2. write your own version of `memset_s()`(EXAMPLE 1). The problem with this is it still not guaranteed to work either - The C standard states that accesses to volatile objects are part of the unalterable observable behaviour — but it says nothing about accesses via lvalue expressions with volatile types
3. to my knowledge the best way is to use a volatile function pointer(EXAMPLE 2)

As a conclusion- whatever you choose it is strongly recommended also to always check the resulting assemdbly code that the memory is actually cleared and none of the memory calls are optimized away.

EXAMPLE 1.

```
static void secure_memzero(void * p, size_t len)
{ 
    volatile uint8_t * _p = p;

    while (len--) *_p++ = 0;
}
```

EXAMPLE 2.

```
static void * (* const volatile memset_ptr)(void *, int, size_t) = memset;

static void secure_memzero(void * p, size_t len)
{

    (memset_ptr)(p, 0, len);
}

void
dosomethingsensitive(void)
{
    uint8_t key[32];

    ...

    /* Zero sensitive information. */
    secure_memzero(key, sizeof(key));
}
```

Comment: Note that `memset_s()` is part of Annex K of the C standard, [which is optional](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note380): "Implementations that do not define `__STDC_LIB_EXT1__` are not required to conform to these specifications."

Comment: Also, Annex K is [probably not going to survive](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm): "Despite more than a decade since the original proposal and nearly ten years since the ratification of ISO/IEC TR 24731-1:2007, and almost five years since the introduction of the Bounds checking interfaces into the C standard, no viable conforming implementations has emerged. ...  **Therefore, we propose that Annex K be either removed from the next revision of the C standard, or deprecated and then removed**."

Answer (score 1):

Probably a good, language neutral way of doing this is to let something depend on the values in memory. For instance, you could first set the memory to all zero, *then* iterate over all bytes, XOR-ing them into a temporary variable. If the answer is other than zero then throw an exception. This exception should of course never happen - but the compiler isn't likely to figure this out (especially if the XOR isn't performed in a different loop construct, hence the requirement to perform the operations in sequence).

This has the additional benefit of throwing an error 
 (with a likelihood of 255 out of 256 if bytes are compared) if the array is altered or if (non-zero) key material is left in the array. This may be a good idea in embedded environments where the execution of the CPU can be altered.

The operation is relatively efficient, as it consists of a single loop with a pre-defined number of looping and a single *if*-construct, besides the memory access of course.

This can be combined with secure ways of setting the contents of the array to zero, as [in the answer of Malin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50186981/589259).